# Hazelcast Management Center com.hazelcast.webmonitor.Launcher

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm currently trying to get the hazelcast management center running locally on my mac, and am getting an error notice, this is it:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.hazelcast.webmonitor.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.webmonitor.Launcher
```

after running:

```
management-center/start.sh
```

inside the root folder.

I can provide more info if needed, I'm kinda new to Hazelcast and am trying to get it working properly so I can use it in junction with the Zeebe workflow engine. Any help would be greatful, and any insight into hazelcast as well, as its a new technology for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I starts clean for me -- MC 4.0.1, OSX 10.15.3, JDK 11.0.6 . What versions are you using ? Could you add the log output please ?

Comment: I'm using similar, MC 4.0.1, OSX 10.15.3, JDK 11.0.2, As for log output, I'm running management-center/start.sh from terminal inside the hazelcast directory and the console is only logging those two lines I shared. Are there any flags I can add to display more descriptive logs?

Answer (score 1):

That is a pathing issue. Please cd to the management-center directory and then execute the start.sh.

7erry:hazelcast-enterprise-3.12.5 twal7ers$ ./management-center/start.sh 
Error: Could not find or load main class Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Launcher

versus:

7erry:management-center twal7ers$ ./start.sh 
2020-03-31 11:12:40 [main] INFO  c.h.webmonitor.config.BuildInfo - Management Center 3.12.7

Hope this helps,